# Can't get function within object to display value

Tags: python, function, object, oop

hey guys I'm currently learning oop but I'm having a bit of trouble with accessing values which I create or add to a object, currently I can't work out how to get the value stored within getAge

```
from datetime import date


class Person:
def __init__(self, name, dob, cob):
    self.name = name
    self.dob = dob
    self.cob = cob

def setName(self, name):
    self.name = name

def getAge(self):
    today = date.today()
    birthYear = int(self.dob[6:]) + 2000
    age = today.year - birthYear
    return age

  


p1 = Person('Jane', '22/06/02', 'England')

p1.setName("Joe")
print(p1.name)

print(Person.getAge)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you print `Person.getAge`, it's a method of `Person`.

`getAge` is a method and not static not, so you need use `p1.getAge()` istead of `Person.getAge` to get the `age` value.

Answer (score 0):

The method getAge only makes sense when using it on an instance of the Person ss. In your case `print(p1.getAge())` to activate the method.

You could also add the `@propery` decorator above the method to avoid the parentheses as the method doesn't require any arguments.